# SQL запрос из 2-х таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `cars` с полями : `id, firma, model, cost`.

Есть вторая связанная таблица `sales` с полями : `id, id_cars, sale`.

Как вывести просто первую таблицу плюс если есть скидка на определенную модель добавить столбец с этой скидкой. Если скидки нет то ничего не добавлять.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так что ли?

```
SELECT cars.id, cars.firma, cars.model, cars.cost, sales.sale
  FROM cars 
  LEFT JOIN sales ON cars.id = sales.id_cars
```

Comment: Спасибо!Вот это скорость!!!!